# Unable to pass updated info from provider to page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been toying with this for hours and tried everything, so I made a very basic not working example of what I need:

server.ts (Provider getting data from server)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ServerProvider {

  basicUrl: any = "http://5.5.5.5/hotel/admin/api.php";

  datos : any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello ServerProvider Provider');
  }


  getInfo() {
    return this.http.get(this.basicUrl).subscribe(result=>{
      this.datos = result;
    });
  }

}
```

tutorial.ts (page that will receive )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ServerProvider } from "../../providers/server/server";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tutorial',
  templateUrl: 'tutorial.html',
})
export class TutorialPage {
  titulo: any;
  datos: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public serverP: ServerProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TutorialPage');
    this.datos = this.serverP.datos;
    this.titulo = this.datos["titulo"];
  }

}
```

tutorial.html (view where the info will show up)

```
<ion-content padding>

    <p>{{titulo}}</p>

</ion-content>
```

I know why this doesn't work, but I can't make observables work for me or any other option to do that.

I need the titulo variable to update every time server.ts getInfo() is called and resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a **Subject** using rxjs, and emits the value using `next()` method in the **Subject**. Whenever the service `getInfo` called, the `datos$` subject will emit the value.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'


@Injectable()
export class ServerProvider {

  basicUrl: any = "http://5.5.5.5/hotel/admin/api.php";

  datos : any;
  datos$ = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello ServerProvider Provider');
  }


  getInfo() {
    return this.http.get(this.basicUrl).subscribe(result=>{
      this.datos = result;
      this.datos$.next(this.datos);
    });
  }

}
```

You should subscribe to the `datos$` in your component.ts, and updates the value emitted from it to the `this.titulo`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ServerProvider } from "../../providers/server/server";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tutorial',
  templateUrl: 'tutorial.html',
})
export class TutorialPage {
  titulo: any;
  datos: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public serverP: ServerProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TutorialPage');
    this.serverP.datos$.subscribe(value => this.titulo = value["titulo"]);

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried something close to this but couldn't figure it out. I'll be marking your answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head define datos as `Subject<any>`. Then whenever you make an update, you call `datos.next`. In your component you start listening to updates in `ngOnint` with `subscribe`. `Subscribe` is called whenever `next` is called, that's why you only need to do it once.

Your code should look something like this:
**server.ts**

```
datos : new Subject<any>();
```

..

```
return this.http.get(this.basicUrl).subscribe(result=>{
      this.datos.next(result);
    });
```

**tutorial.ts**

```
export class TutorialPage implements OnInit {
  titulo: any;
  datos: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public serverP: ServerProvider) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.serverP.datos.subscribe((datos) => this.titulo = this.datos["titulo"]);
  }
```

..

Comment: Thank you! I've tried something close to this but couldn't figure it out. Since the answer below it's a bit more complete I'll mark that one ut this is basically the same approach. Thanks!